# Sort and Group React Native SectionList by Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, react-native, expo

I have a SectionList which I populate with data from firebase. The list shows event info sectioned by date, with the current month visible as `THIS MONTH` and the other dates using their shorthand value of `JAN`, `FEB` etc..

I get the data fine and can display it fine but I can't figure out how to group the data array by the dates. FYI the dates are saved in the db as date strings '`2019-01-05`' and i use moment to format them with this method:

```
 formatDateToMonth(date) {
  let fullDate = moment(date);
  fullDate.month();
  const month = fullDate.format('MMM');
  return month.toUpperCase();
}
```

Which returns `JAN`. I run a simple `if` statement to check the value of title against the current month which I format with moment and if its a match I change the display name of title to `THIS MONTH`.

The data is pushed to an array like so:

```
listData.push({
  data: [
    {
      id: event,
      eventName: eventObj.eventName,
      location: eventObj.location,
      description: eventObj.description,
      creatorsName: eventObj.creatorsName,
      date: eventObj.date,
      discipline: eventObj.discipline
    }
  ],
  title
});
```

With the title being the month name and the key that I need to sort and group this by.

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

This is how I would like it to look: (used dummy data to present it correctly)
[image]

I would like each event that is in the same month to be under the same section.

Any help would be amazing!

FULL COMPONENT:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, SectionList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content , Text, Icon, Spinner } from 'native-base';
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';
import {f, auth, database} from '../../config/config';
import _ from 'lodash';

import CustomIcon from '../utilities/CustomIcon';

import Month from './Month';
import moment from 'moment';
import Day from './Day';

let today = moment();
let now = today.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
let getCurrentMonth = today.month('MMM');

const monthOrder = [
  'JAN',
  'FEB',
  'MAR',
  'APR',
  'MAY',
  'JUN',
  'JUL',
  'AUG',
  'SEPT',
  'OCT',
  'NOV',
  'DEC'
];

class SectionListItem extends React.Component {

  state = {
    descriptionCollapsed: true
  };

  toggleDescription = () => {
    this.setState({ descriptionCollapsed: !this.state.descriptionCollapsed
    });
  };

  render() {
    let fullDay = moment(this.props.item.date);
    fullDay.day();
    const day = fullDay.format('DD')
    return (
      <View style={styles.sectionListItemContainer}>
      <View style={styles.eventInfoContainer}>
      <View>
      <Day day={day}/>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDescription}>
      <View style={styles.info}>
      <Text style={styles.eventName}>{this.props.item.eventName.toUpperCase()}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.creatorsName}>Coached by {this.props.item.creatorsName}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.location}>{this.props.item.location}</Text>
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.descriptionCollapsed}>
      <EventDescription description={this.props.item.description} discipline={this.props.item.discipline}/>
    </Collapsible>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

class EventDescription extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.descriptionDropdown}>
      <View >
      <Icon name='arrow-up' type="SimpleLineIcons" style={styles.upArrow} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.description}>{this.props.description}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
      {!!this.props.discipline ? (this.props.discipline.map((item, index) => {
      return <View key={index} style={styles.iconMargin}><CustomIcon name={item} size={20} style={styles.iconStyle}/></View>
    })) : null}
  </View>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

class SectionHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.monthHeader}>
      <Month month={this.props.section.title}/>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

export default class EventList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filterCollapsed: true,
      listData: [],
      loading: true,
      refreshing: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadEvents();
  }

  onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({refreshing: true})
    this.loadEvents();
  }

  formatDateToMonth(date) {
    let fullDate = moment(date);
    fullDate.month();
    const month = fullDate.format('MMM');
    return month.toUpperCase();
  }

  getDateMatches = (date) => {
    return database
      .ref('events')
      .orderByChild('date')
      .startAt(date)
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let matches = [];
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          let val = child.val();
          const valMonth = this.formatDateToMonth(val.date);
          const dateMonth = this.formatDateToMonth(date);
          if (dateMonth === valMonth) {
            matches.push(val);
          }
        });
        return matches;
      });
  }

  loadEvents = () => {
    this.setState({listData: []});
    const that = this;

    database.ref('events').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
      if (exists) {
        data = snapshot.val();
      }
      const listData = that.state.listData;

      let monthData = {title: '', data: []};

      const thisMonth = { title: 'THIS MONTH', data: []};
      const otherMonth = { title: '', data: []};

      for(var event in data) {
        const eventObj = data[event];

        const month = this.formatDateToMonth(eventObj.date);
        let title;

        getCurrentMonth.month();
        const currentMonth = getCurrentMonth.format('MMM');


        if (month === currentMonth.toUpperCase()) {
          title = 'THIS MONTH';
        } else {
          title = month;
        }

        listData.push(
          {
            data: [
              {
                id: event,
                eventName: eventObj.eventName,
                location: eventObj.location,
                description: eventObj.description,
                creatorsName: eventObj.creatorsName,
                date: eventObj.date,
                discipline: eventObj.discipline,
              }
            ],
            title
          }
        );

        // listData.sort((a, b) => {
        //     return (a.title - b.title) || (monthOrder.indexOf(a.title) - monthOrder.indexOf(b.title))
        // });



        that.setState({loading: false, refreshing: false});

      }

    }).catch(error => console.log('error: ', error));
  }


  toggleFilter = () => {
    this.setState({ filterCollapsed: !this.state.filterCollapsed });
  };

  render() {

    if (!!this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.spinner}>
        <Spinner color="#81e6fc"/>
        </View>
    )
    }

    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.filterTextContainer} onPress={this.toggleFilter}>
      <Text style={styles.filterText}>FILTER</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.filterCollapsed}>
      <CustomIcon name="Rate" size={50} style={styles.iconStyle}/>
    </Collapsible>
    <Content contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
    onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      >
      <SectionList
    renderItem={({item, index}) => {
      return <SectionListItem item={item} index={index}/>
    }}
    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => {
      return <SectionHeader section={section}/>
    }}
    sections={dummyData}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
  >
  </SectionList>
    </Content>
    </Container>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code for your entire component?

Comment: @dentemm sure hang on

Comment: Hey did you get the answer ? @molebox

Comment: @VinayN I did: https://github.com/molebox/familia/blob/master/components/mainApp/schedule/EventList.js

Comment: @molebox Hi, could you please check this and show how can I filter title and data part separately? I still don't get it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525341/how-to-filter-from-two-different-arrays-in-react-native

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you do not care about years in your groupping, because in that case 2018-01 and 2019-01 would both be JAN. But anyway take a look at example below, I tried to comment every step in code:

```js
// define your flat list of events
const events = [
 {name: 'dummy one', date: '2019-01-05'},
 {name: 'dummy some', date: '2019-02-04'},
 {name: 'dummy another', date: '2019-01-07'},
 {name: 'dummy really dummy', date: '2019-04-05'},
 {name: 'dummy and funny', date: '2019-06-05'},
 {name: 'dummy not funny', date: '2019-06-22'}
].sort((a, b) => a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1)
// remember to sort them early so you will not have to worry about it anytime later on

// extract distinct names from available events, we are using Set constructor to make sure any key won't be doubled and also that there won't be any empty month
const groupNames = Array.from(new Set(events.map(k => k.date.split('-')[1]))) // split date by hyphen and return only month part

// define place for groups
let groups = {}

// create groups containers from names
groupNames.forEach(k => {
 groups[k] = []
})

// iterate by events and attach every to given group based on its month
events.forEach(k => {
 const month = k.date.split('-')[1]
  groups[month].push(k)
})

// container for demo purposes
let resultHTML = ''

// iterate by groups, if you are unsure about 'for in' loop, use groupNames for that part, and then iterate by events in every group
for(let key in groups) {
 resultHTML += `<h2>${key}</h2>`
  for (let event of groups[key]) {
   resultHTML += `<p>${event.date} &mdash; ${event.name}</p>`
  }
}

// display results for demo purposes
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = resultHTML
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Holy shit that looks great, im going to try running your examples against my code and see if it works. I have already formatted the date to extract the month and i also run a sort after the array has been populated. But i will give your functions a go and see if it works. Hang tight...

Comment: @molebox you're welcome :) If It's what you wanted- do not hesitate to accept the answer. thanks

Comment: will do. Im still trying to adapt your answer to my code but i think its on the right track. As soon as i get it working i’ll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @MaciejKwas Hi, could you please help me on this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525341/how-to-filter-from-two-different-arrays-in-react-native